# Query key condition not supported, python

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

```
response = tblEth_orders.query(
    IndexName = 'date-index',
    KeyConditionExpression= '#temp >= :myDate',
    ExpressionAttributeValues= {   
        ':myDate': week_ago_t
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames= {
        "#temp": "date"
    }
   )

response = response['Items']
print(response)
```

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Query key condition not supported

Please tell me another method to solve this error.

Comment: Please provide more details about the table and the index

Comment: [
  {'AttributeName': 'date', 'AttributeType': 'S'}, 
  {'AttributeName': 'listing_id', 'AttributeType': 'S'}, 
  {'AttributeName': 'order_id', 'AttributeType': 'S'}, 
  {'AttributeName': 'username', 'AttributeType': 'S'}
]
About Table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the key condition is incorrect.

- If your index ('date-index') only has a partition key then you can only use the '=' operator in the key condition expression. You can only fetch.
- If your index ('date-index') has a partition key and a sort key then you can use the '=' operator in the key condition expression for the partition key and almost any standard comparison operator for the sort key. Operators like '<', '>' and many others.

See here for documentation about the available operators:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html